# Questions on commercial music?

Tags: discussion, topics

Where do I ask questions on information on commercial music?
Eg: Chord progressions, lyrics, instruments used etc?

Can I ask it in "Music: Practice & Theory" or is there another place?

Answer (score 4):

The "commercial-ness" of the music doesn't have any bearing on whether or not a question is on topic here. If it's a question that a musician would be asking about the theory or practice of that music, the question will likely be on-topic. If the question is something a non-musician might ask--or what we might call a "music appreciation" question, then it is not on-topic here.

Comment: Ok, as a rapper, I might want to know certain lyrics which may be very hard to find otherwise on the internet, does that count?

Comment: That would be classified as a transcription question and would be off-topic here, but may be allowed on Music Fans.

Comment: thanks @NReilingh, could you provide a link to Music Fans?

Comment: It hasn't launched yet, but will be launching soon. The answers below have links to the Area51 site, where you can commit to the proposal and be notified when it goes live.

Comment: Thanks @NReilingh, I've done that.

Answer (score 2):

It depends a lot on exactly what you mean. As I read your question, I'm pretty certain these kind of questions will be off topic here, but you can ask at the [Music Fans](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans?referrer=nZ53IExUjKRlGleSE5XxcQ2) site.

The [beta site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans) will launch really soon, so commit to it! Have a look at the example questions there to see what that site scope will be.